# Is it possible to set up virtual machines(Virtual box etc) inside Microsoft Azure(hyper-v)

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v, azure

I want to set up Microsoft MOC machines inside Microsoft Azure

Since Azure is already running on hyper-v, it is not possible to run another hyper-v inside azure machines

But is it possible to install VirtualBox or any other alternates inside azure machines for setting up MOCs?

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to use nested virtualization in Azure. It's now available for VM types Dv3 and Ev3.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/

Answer (score 1):

It's not only possible, but actually the only option to use [Azure nested virtualization](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/). That's because Microsoft MOC machines are VHD files for Microsoft Hyper-V, so you can't just use any Type-2 (hosted) hypervisor, like VirtualBox, that uses its own virtual disk format.

Comment: Sorry, wrong. Not by long, but MS changed that like "this week" or so.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that yet! Then, Bruno's answer already covers the subject, so I'll just remove mine.